# Can I choose to not sort directories before files on file open dialogs?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk-2

I would prefer to not have directories sorted before files within the file open/save dialogs. I would like everything sorted by modification date regardless of file or directory.

I have done a fair amount of googleing with trial and error still without a solution.

*specifics*

- xubuntu 14.04
- no desktop enviornment, gui started via `startx`
- thunar version 1.6.3
- gtk2 version 2.24.23
- gtk3 version 3.10.8

Answer (score 10):

I have a solution for GTK applications, and a solution for dolphin.  I've never figured out how to fix this for non-GTK applications (e.g., LibreOffice).

For GTK:

1. Fire up `dconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to `org/gtk/settings/file-chooser`.
3. De-select the box next to `sort-directories-first`.
4. Close the dialog.

For dolphin:

1. Navigate to Control / Sort by >.
2. De-select "Folders first" at the bottom of the menu.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:  I see someone else asked / addressed this problem [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271508).  I mention it because that thread has an easy command-line answer for the GTK+ part:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-directories-first true
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't have an option `sort-directories-first` nor do I also don't have dolphin installed.

Comment: OK - you don't have dolphin because you have nautilus.  They are just somewhat different system file management programs. But to address the GTK issue specifically:  try the command `gsettings list-keys org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser` and see if there is something in there mentioning sorting or directories.  The key that exists on my system is `sort-directories-first`. If that key is there, then try the command-line version I gave above. If not ... you can also try `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.nautilus.preferences` and look for an equivalent key there.

Comment: I have neither nautilus nor dolphin. I have the default xubuntu file manager, thunar. Still no results on the commands either. Thanks though

Comment: Thanks! Dolphin default sort order was driving me nuts.... I was searching under preferences/settings/whatever to get it to sort like normal `ls`... I rarely look at & use "toolbars" -- the option was hidden in plain sight. (Still, it's a stupid UI/usability choice, but it's still better than f'ing nautilus 16.10+, which is completely hozed.)

Comment: Or `dconf write /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/sort-directories-first true`, `gsettings` mode did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Thunar just set the option in the (edit>)preferences under view.

Comment: This doesn't change the sort order for the file open/save dialogs of firefox or chromium though?